# Image and Font Menu Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css, wordpress, vertical-alignment

While I've used wordpress for quite some time, in the spirit of full transparency I am limited when it comes to coding. I don't build from scratch.  I use themes and add customization where I can.  I tend to go with try and error and work my way through problems, but after 2 days and no results I thought I'd post.

I'm currently working with an author to update her website (http://www.kerriedroban.com). She would like her flying pig logo next to her menu item "Why Pigs Fly".  I was able to find a plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-images/) that allowed from an image and font in the menu.  However, as you can see the image pushes the "Why Pigs Fly" lower than the other menu items....I assume because it is aligning with the baseline and not the center.

I figure the easiest answer would be to scale the image down but I don't want to make the image any smaller as it will not be visible. Is there a code that will make allow them to be vertically aligned?

I am currently using the Arctica Theme by AIT Themes. Per the Editor it states I should make changes to the  style.less.css.

This is the the menu info that is included in it:

```
/*** main menu ***/ 
.fixed                      {position:relative;}
#fixedmenu                  {position:fixed; min-width: 1024px; margin-bottom:20px;z-index: 1100;}
#fixedmenu .flags           { position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 30px; padding: 0px; display: block; }
#fixedmenu .flags a         { display: block; float: left; margin-left: 8px; border: 1px solid @linesColor; }
#fixedmenu .flags a.active  { margin-left: 18px; }
#fixedmenu .flags a img     { vertical-align: top; }

.phoneNumber { color: @menusFontColor; margin: 0px; font-size:14px; font-family: @fancyFont;font-weight:normal; }

.mainmenu                               {background: @menuBgColor url("{@menuPattern}")repeat; border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px; box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);position:relative; }
.mainmenu ul                            { list-style-type: none; margin: 0 30px; }
.mainmenu ul:after                      { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; overflow:hidden; clear: both; visibility: hidden; 
.mainmenu ul li                         { margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px; float: left; position: relative;}
.mainmenu > ul > li,
.mainmenu > .menu > ul > li             { line-height: 26px; display: block; }
.mainmenu > ul > li > a,
.mainmenu > .menu > ul > li > a         { font-family: @fancyFont, Arial, sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: @menusFontColor; font-size: 16px; padding:12px 0 16px 0; position: relative; z-index: 1000; display: block; }
.mainmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
.mainmenu > .menu > ul > li > a:hover   { text-decoration: none; color: @menusFontColor; }
.mainmenu > ul > li.parent:hover > a,
.mainmenu > .menu ul > li.parent:hover > a                  {  }
.mainmenu > ul > li.current_page_item > a,
.mainmenu > ul > li.current_page_parent > a,`
.mainmenu > ul > li.current_page_ancestor > a,
.mainmenu > .menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a,
.mainmenu > .menu > ul > li.current_page_parent > a,
.mainmenu > .menu > ul > li.current_page_ancestor > a       { color: @menusActiveFontColor !important; }
.mainmenu ul ul                     { width: 200px; padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; display: none; position: absolute;  top: 45px; left: 0px; margin: 0; background: #fff; border:2px solid #eee;border-top: 12px solid #eee;border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
.mainmenu li li                     { width: 200px; height: 25px; float: none; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px; position: relative; }
.mainmenu li li a                   { display: block; padding: 3px 7px 3px 7px; background: none; color: #666666; text-decoration: none; }
.mainmenu li ul > li:hover > a      { background: #eee; color: #000000; text-decoration: none;}
.mainmenu ul ul ul                  { position: absolute; top: -13px; left: 204px; }
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just attach custom class in WordPress and add background-image to this class?

---

Add this to your CSS:

```
.pig:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url('http://kerriedroban.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/red-pig-small-e1440441375424.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
.pig a {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

And add `pig` class to desired menu item.

Comment: I'd be happy to try that.  Just don't know how.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @HHenry In WordPress  go to Appearance > Menus, in right top corner click  _screen options_, check _CSS Classes_. Now when you expand any menu item you will see you have text input where you can specify your custom class.

Comment: would this take the place of the plugin?

Initially I did as instructed and deactivate plugin, then there was no image at all.

Then I reactivated plugin and the pig is still too low.

Comment: @HHenry When you have class you need to set `background` to that class. I was sure you understand it :D Add in CSS file: `.pig {background: url('path-to-your-image.jpg') no-repeat left top;}`. Then in WordPress add `pig` class to desired menu item. Of course you have to change `path-to-your-image.jpg` to your path.

Comment: While this isn't exactly as I initially wanted I think this may work.  I'll check with the author. Thanks!

Comment: @HHenry I like what you have now but I think I know what you want. I've updated my answer, try it.

Comment: Yes, Definitely better!  Thank you!!

Comment: @HHenry If you like my answer you could accept it :)